# How to read read values from a line of text file properly into a matrix using matlab

Tags: matlab

x=cell2mat(textscan(line,'%*s%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f','CollectOutput',1,'EmptyValue',0));

given values as 
R17  19311104.430 8 103337621.26208                                  19311107.476 7

I should get output as 
19311104.4300000    8   103337621.262080    0   0   0   0  19311107.4760000 7

but getting as
19311104.4300000    8   103337621.262080    19311107.4760000    7   0   0   0   0

Answer (score 0):

why do you assume the output

```
19311104.4300000 8 103337621.262080 0 0 0 0 19311107.4760000 7
```

from the input

```
R17 19311104.430 8 103337621.26208 19311107.476 7
```

?

Your operation `textscan(line,'%*s%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f','CollectOutput',1,'EmptyValue',0)` is collecting 9 floating point numbers from the input string. 
Your input string only lists 5 floating-point numbers, meaning that the first 5 `%f` get a value, while the remaining 4 will become `NaN` (or in your case `0` due to your `'EmptyValue',0` parameter).

Therefore, everything works as expected.

However, if you would like to achieve your desired result you need to use some more "fancy" algorithm, e.g.:

```
x = zeros(1,9);
tmp=cell2mat(textscan(line,'%*s%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f','CollectOutput',1));
x(1:3)=tmp(1:3);
x(end-1:end) = tmp(4:5)
```